# Solve a second order nonlinear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a second order nonlinear equation:

$$-u''+ \frac{1}{4}(u')^2+au=x^2.$$

I am only interested in the solutions in $[0, \frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{1}{a^2}]$. One paper claims without proof that the unique solution should be

$$u(x)=(\sqrt{a^2+4}-a)\big(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{a}\big).$$

Does anyone have some ideas how to calculate the solution (without guessing the form of quadratic polynomial) and how to prove the uniqueness?

Thank you!

Comment: I would approach this by converting it into a matrix,  $ z= (u' )^2 $ if someone answers and has some free time could they comment about approaching it that way i'm really curious about this one but its been too long since i did something at this level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can trivially see that a solution could be of the form 
$$
u(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma \tag{1}
$$
trialing wih Eq. (1)
we find
$$
-2\alpha + \frac{1}{4}\left(2\alpha x + \beta\right)^2 + a\left(\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma\right) = x^2
$$
comparing coefficents we find
$$
-2\alpha + \frac{\beta^2}{4} + a\gamma = 0\;\;\text{$x^0$ terms}\\
\alpha\beta + a\beta = \beta(\alpha + a) = 0\;\;\text{$x$ terms}\\
\alpha^2 + a\alpha = \alpha(\alpha+a) = 1\;\;\text{$x^2$ terms}
$$

From the coefficients for $x$ and $x^2$ we require $\alpha + a\neq 0$ thus $\beta = 0$
therefore
$$
-2\alpha +a\gamma = 0 \implies \gamma = \frac{2\alpha}{a}
$$
the solution Eq.(1) is of the form with a constant
$$
u(x) = 2\alpha\left(\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{a}\right)\tag{2}
$$
now to find $\alpha$
we know that
$$
\alpha^2 + a\alpha = 1 \implies \alpha^2 + a\alpha -1 = 0
$$
solutions of the above quadratic is
$$
\alpha = \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2 +4}}{2} 
$$
or
$$
2\alpha = -a\pm\sqrt{a^2 +4}
$$
now we can put into Eq.(2)
$$
u(x) = \left(\pm\sqrt{a^2 +4}-a\right)\left(\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{a}\right)
$$
since we are looking for solutions $>0$ at least, we can eliminate (-) from the $\pm$ above.

Comment: Thanks! However, why the solution must be in the form of quadratic polynomial?

Comment: It was a trial function that I would of used even if I didn't know the solution I was aiming for.. so are you asking why I picked the quadratic?

Comment: I am asking why this is the unique solution in $[0,\frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{1}{a}]$ ($a$ is supposed to be a small number).

Comment: As for polynomials go this is the unique equation. To proof uniqueness for nonlinear ode is usual not possible in terms of picking two unique solutions and proceeding. But with nonlinear odes I would be happy a solution exists (as placed by God himself ;) ha) I am still pushing on with a nonlinear ode that has defeated me for 5 years and counting ..